# Error while building worker image from example voting app

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-build

I am getting below error while building worker image from example voting app. I am on Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS.

```
Error -
root@ubuntu2004:/home/ubuntu/study/docker/example-voting-app/worker# docker build . -t worker
Sending build context to Docker daemon 10.24kB
Step 1/13 : FROM --platform=${BUILDPLATFORM} mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 as build
failed to parse platform : “” is an invalid component of “”: platform specifier component must match"^[A-Za-z0-9_-]+$": invalid argument
```

Dockerfile -
https://github.com/dockersamples/example-voting-app/blob/main/worker/Dockerfile

I tried with below Dockerfile but its also giving me an error.

Dockerfile -
https://github.com/mmumshad/example-voting-app/blob/master/worker/Dockerfile

```
Error - file does exists in mentioned location

Step 3/10 : COPY src/Worker/Worker.csproj .
COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat src/Worker/Worker.csproj: file does not exist
```

I have just started learning docker, Can someone please help.

Comment: Can you try the first command with `docker buildx build . -t worker`

Comment: The command is not working, its giving me an output as "See docker --help".

Answer (score 0):

I  had the same error message: BUILDPLATFORM was empty.

After updating docker, it worked.

For updating docker see the docs: https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/